# Template specialization with dependent values

Tags: c++, templates, class-template

Using templates for array size seems straightforward:

```
template <size_t N>
struct MyArray
{
    char array[N];
};
```

What I'd like to do, though, is set the array size based on something else:

```
enum MyEnum {Hi, Lo};

template <MyEnum T, size_t N>
struct MyArray
{
    MyEnum type() { return T; }
    char array[N];
};
```

How do I set N to 10 when MyEnum is Hi, and 200 when MyEnum is Lo?

What I'd like to do is say

```
MyArray<Lo> lo; // Result in MyArray<Lo, 200>
MyArray<Hi> hi; // Result in MyArray<Hi, 10>
```

rather than having to say

```
MyArray<Lo, 200> lo;
MyArray<Hi, 10> hi;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a default value for `N` right away, same as you'd do with normal function parameters:

```
enum MyEnum { Hi, Lo };

template <MyEnum T, size_t N = (T == Hi ? 10 : 200)> // parentheses for clarity
struct MyArray { ... };
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb1b6ac0584cc84c)

Comment: Note that allows `MyArray<Hi, 42>` (that may be a bonus, or a non-desired behavior)...

Answer (score 5):

You have several possibilities

Use the computation of `N` directly in the main class:

```
template <MyEnum E>
class MyArray
{
    constexpr std::size_t N = (E == Hi ? 10 : 200);
public:
    MyEnum type() { return E; }
    char array[N];
};
```

or specialize

```
template <MyEnum E> struct MyArraySize;
template <> struct MyArraySize<Hi> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 10> {};
template <> struct MyArraySize<Low> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 200>{};

template <MyEnum E>
class MyArray
{
public:
    MyEnum type() { return E; }
    char array[MyArraySize<E>::value];
};
```

Comment: You should note that in your first option, constexpr is C++11 only

Comment: @BrettStottlemyer: We are now in 2016, so I would say that if c++03 is wanted, it should be mentioned in Q. In C++03, you may use the `enum` trick instead of `constexpr` here. And for the second option, `integral_constant` (which is also C++11) may be implemented in C++03.